# How to determine length of array in O(log n) time, by only calling A[i]?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have an array of unknown length `n`, where each element of the array is the number 1. So its like `A=[1,1,1,1.....]`, `n` times. Now I need to write an algorithm to find out the value of `n`.

Here is the full problem statement:

> You are given an array `A` of length `n`. Each value is 1. However, you do not know what the value of `n` is. You are allowed to access an element `i` of the array by calling `A[i]`. If `i < n`, this will return 1, and if `i >= n`, this will return a message saying that the location does not exist (you can think of this as an error message, but it will not crash your program). Describe an O(log n) algorithm to determine the value of `n`.

This is what I have come up with :

```
Set i = 1;
while A(i-1) is true // i.e. for i <= n, it will return the element for the index (i-1)
      print i_old = i
      print i_new = 2i // doubling the value of i
      i = i_new // to run the loop again to check the array A with new value of i
else
     print no element found // when i>n
```

Now, this means the last index is between the last pair of `i_old` and `i_new`.
So, for an array `[1,1,1,1,1,1]` of six elements the value of `n` can be between 4 and 6, i.e. it can be either 4 or 5.
I am not sure about how to proceed further. What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not sure I understand--you need the length of the array in pseudocode? Seems like a property defined by the language and not something you can write an algorithm for in pseudocode. Arrays "just have" a length implicitly. In pseudocode you can say `length(arr)` and voila, you have the length of the array. Can you clarify the purpose of this exercise? Thanks.

Comment: Where does the `6` value appear?  Your algorithm generates only powers of 2.  I'm unclear how you imagine this algorithm to work.  First, most languages will throw a run-time error when you access `A(8)` when there are only 6 elements.  Second, most languages give access to the array length as a property, since they need to track it anyway.  You seem to operate with assumptions and restrictions you haven't specified.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: Thanks everyone for asking, i actually need to design an algorithm that will give me the length of an array whose size is n, where n is unknown. The array consists of 1 as its elements.

Comment: @Blue_Leaf Try 1, then 2, then 4, then 8... until you get the error message. Then you know it's between 2^k and 2^(k+1) for some k, so you can do a binary search between them.

Comment: This is known as an [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search).

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this using the [exponential search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) in O(log n) time:

Assume the length is 2. Try successive powers of 2 (2, 4, 8, 16...) until an out of bounds exception is raised. This gives a guarantee of an upper bound on the possible length. Perform a [right binary search](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3c88199e0be352c0813f145d7c4c83af044268aa/Lib/bisect.py#L15) between 0 and this upper bound. On each bisection iteration, if the midpoint index doesn't raise an exception, try the upper half of the search space, else try the lower half. When our bounds meet, return that index.

Python implementation:

```
def length(L):
    lo = 0
    hi = 1

    while 1:
        hi *= 2

        try: 
            L[hi]
        except IndexError:
            break

    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2

        try:
            L[mid]
            lo = mid + 1
        except IndexError:
            hi = mid 

    return hi

if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert all(length([1] * i) == i for i in range(1000))
```

Comment: `lo = hi // 2` is a better initial lower bound.

Comment: Sure, that saves an iteration.